# Difference Between Rails 2.2 and 2.3.5? ActionMailer.Utils

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would think this is a Ruby difference, but I'm using the same Ruby version 1.8.7. This is related to [this post](http://blog.thoughtobject.com/2007/05/26/5/) (to answer "why do you need this?"). This code works in 2.2.2

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.2.2)
>> module ActionMailer
>> Utils.normalize_new_lines("blah")
>> end
```

but in 2.3.5 it fails

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
>> module ActionMailer
>> Utils.normalize_new_lines("blah")
>> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `normalize_new_lines' for ActionMailer::Utils:Module
from (irb):2
```

What's new about 2.3.5 that this would fail? The method is there in 2.3.5, so this works

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
>> include ActionMailer
>> include Utils
>> normalize_new_lines("blah")
```

I realize this is probably an important Rails difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the code changed from [version 2.2](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.2.0/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/utils.rb) to [version 2.3.5](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.5/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/utils.rb)

old:

```
module ActionMailer
  module Utils #:nodoc:
    def normalize_new_lines(text)
      text.to_s.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")
    end
    module_function :normalize_new_lines
  end
end
```

new:

```
module ActionMailer
  module Utils #:nodoc:
    def normalize_new_lines(text)
      text.to_s.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")
    end
  end
end
```

I guess you could restore the old behavior by calling `module_function` yourself:

```
$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
>> module ActionMailer
>> module Utils
>> module_function :normalize_new_lines
>> end
>> Utils.normalize_new_lines("blah")
>> end
=> "blah"
>>
```

**EDIT**: Or better yet just include the module (per [Simone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/simone-carletti))

`>> include ActionMailer::Utils`

Comment: Also, I would suggest to include the module instead of restoring the old behavior. If it changes, there's a reason for that. IMHO the implementation should follow the library, instead of reverting the library to follow our implementation. Otherwise, other problems might arise in the future.

Comment: @Simone Carletti, since the plugin I'm using "patches" ActionMailer, I added "include Utils" to that patch. It works. Is that a bad idea? @Zetetic thank you for tracking this down. I will be more likely to read the source myself in the future.

Comment: @yar just make sure you aren't including the module twice.

Comment: @Simone Carletti, any way to check that after the fact? I know that if I don't include it, I get a method not found error. Otherwise the method is found.